# How to authenticate an Universal App (Windows 8.1/WindowsPhone 8.1) app using the Facebook App (not with webviews)

Tags: facebook, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to get my app to use the FACEBOOK offical app to login .. I DO NOT want to use oAuth , WebAuthenticationBroker .

Something like this: http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.pt/2014/03/direct-facebook-login-support-available.html  but for Universal Apps

I known it is possible I just can't find any information on how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Facebook documentation is available for Windows Phone: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone

But for Windows it says:

> If you are building Login for a Windows app you can use the Package Security Identifier as your redirect_uri. Trigger the Login Dialog by calling WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync and use the Login Dialog endpoint as the requestUri. Here is an example ...

So I think it's not possible...

If you try to call the Facebook app with

```
string FbUri = "fbconnect://authorize?client_id=...";
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(FbUri));
```

It says there are no apps associated with the fbconnect protocol...

Comment: But for WindowsPhone 8.1 it finds the app!

Comment: Yes, you can for phone but not for Windows

Comment: this defeats the purpose of Universal Apps :S